# Setting the text size without setting the margins

Tags: pdftex, memoir

I am working with a complex Greek text with apparatus and I need to provide the publisher with the result in the form of pages with text of the previously agreed special size. Due to their publishing process (Indesign) they will be importing these pages themselves, so I basically have no control over their margins. Is there a way to set only one parameter, the vertical and horizontal text size without setting the margins?

Comment: Not sure it fully answers what you have in mind, but the `geometry` package has a `papersize=` and a `layoutsize=` parameters. You also can choose the ratio of the inner margin and the outer margin, or of the top and bottom margins.

Comment: Thank you, this is probably what I need.